# Jquery plugins not working properly in firefox should I check for firefox and run a different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a plugin I am playing around with, maybe implement into my site somewhere on my site.

[Link here for demo](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/)

Its nice and simple and leaves a lot of room for customization and design. All is good but the new page function doesn't add pages in Firefox at all. I just get this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).booklet is not a function
```

So is it possible to check if the user is using firefox to run a different script to refesh the page or something like that.

Booklet included as per example given o the site:

```
$("#mag_pages").booklet({
        width:pw+'px',
        height:'100%',
        pageNumbers: false,
        overlays: true, 
        next: "#next_page",
        prev: "#prev_page",
        change: function(event,data){
            alert(data.pages[0]['title']);
        },
        add : function(event, data){
            alert('pages added');
        }
    });
```

This works all right I have my own next and previous buttons which work on all browsers.

Comment: No, do not detect the browser... fix the problem instead... How are you including the booklet plugin?

Comment: its not my code, its a plugin developed by somebody else. To do this what would i look for in the source code as the reason for the plugin is I'm not that good at jquery

Comment: right, but i kinda doubt this is a problem with the plugin itself.

Comment: No follow the link using firefox, same problem on there

Comment: it works for me in firefox.

Comment: what version you using?

Comment: 28.0 *"Firefox is up to date"* windows.

Comment: No still the same, could just be my machine

Comment: Please do not put your solution in the question.  Please post your solution below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The version jquery easing on the source is outdated doesn't really cause a problem but its worth updating anyway.

[v1.3](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js) not v1.1 in the source code

Can't offer a deep explanation of how this fixes the problem. But by running Firefox in safe mode and restarting the plugins helped. The links below are particularly useful.

[Useful post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/980903)

[Reset firefox in safemode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)